# How to solve this recurrence with two initial conditions using repertoire

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was reading a textbook with the following recurrence example:

$$
a_n = (n-1)a_{n-1} - na_{n-2} + n-1 \quad \text{for } n > 1 \text{ with } a_0=a_1=1
$$

From the example, we set $f(n)=n-1$, so that $a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}-na_{n-2}+f(n)$.

Using  candidates $1$, $n$ and $n^2$ for $a_n$, we get the following repertoire table:

$$(1)\quad  a_n=1 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad f(n) = a_n - (n-1)a_{n-1} + na_{n-2}=2$$
$$(2) \quad a_n=n \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad f(n) = a_n - (n-1)a_{n-1} + na_{n-2}=n-1$$
$$(3) \quad a_n=n^2 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad f(n) = a_n - (n-1)a_{n-1} + na_{n-2}=n+1$$

From the table, we already have a solution for $f(n)=n-1$, which is $(2)$, where $a_n=n$, with initial conditions $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$.

We can also subtract $(1)$ from $(3)$ to get $a_n=n^2-1$. The linear combination of $(3)-(1)$ results in $f(n)=n-1$ as well with initial conditions $a_0=-1$ and $a_1=0$.

However, from this point on I got lost. The text says that we can combine linearly independent solutions $a_n=n$ and $a_n=n^2-1$ to get the 'right' initial values (where $a_0=a_1=1$) so that the final answer is $a_n=n^2-n+1$.

I could not figure out how the final answer is $a_n=n^2-n+1$.

$a_n=n^2-n+1$ seems to be a linear combination as well of $(3)-(2)+(1)$. But if we add them up we get $f(n)=4$ which is not $f(n)=n-1$, even though its initial values match up to $a_0=a_1=1$.

Any help?

Comment: I highly doubt the answer is as simple as $a_n = n^2 - n + 1$. Using generating functions I got the initial value problem $$(1-z)A'(z)-\left(2 z^2+1\right) A(z)+1+z+\frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2}=0,\ \ A(0)=1,$$ which Mathematica solved as $$ -\frac{(5 F(1)+1) e^{-z (z+2)}-5 F(z+1)-z^2+z+1}{2 (z-1)^3},$$ where $F(z) = e^{-z^2}\int_0^z e^{t^2}\ \mathsf dt$. Good luck finding an analytical solution for the series of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This realtion
$$a_n = (n-1)a_{n-1} - na_{n-2} + n-1 \qquad \text{for } n > 1\quad \text{ with }\quad a_0=a_1=1$$
generates interesting numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 0 \\
 3 & -1 \\
 4 & 0 \\
 5 & 9 \\
 6 & 50 \\
 7 & 243 \\
 8 & 1308 \\
 9 & 8285 \\
 10 & 61494 \\
 11 & 523815 \\
 12 & 5024048 \\
 13 & 53478993 \\
 14 & 624890250 \\
 15 & 7946278619 \\
 16 & 109195935300 \\
 17 & 1612048228293 \\
 18 & 25439293045598 \\
 19 & 427278358483215 \\
 20 & 7609502950269144 \\
 21 & 143217213477235385 \\
 22 & 2840152418116021938 \\
 23 & 59189357288576068803 \\
 24 & 1293191559602465055980 \\
 25 & 29556863498244759623469 \\
 26 & 705298606906454899131270 \\
 27 & 17539728465115218867579383 \\
 28 & 453824307564730172248967808 \\
 29 & 12198428486324103475811296545 \\
 30 & 340139696876457095631058565594
\end{array}
\right)$$
A quick and dirty regression (for $ 5 \leq n \leq 30$) gives $(R^2=0.999984)$
$$\log(a_n)=0.51633\, n^{1.44998}-3.31609$$ where the parameters are highly significant.
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -3.31609 & 0.16768 & \{-3.66384,-2.96835\} \\
 b & +0.51633 & 0.01529 & \{+0.48463,+0.54803\} \\
 c & +1.44998 & 0.00829 & \{+1.43278,+1.46718\} \\
\end{array}$$

Quite far away from a polynomial.

Are you sure about the equation ?

Comment: thanks, sorry it's been a while since i looked at this question ... i checked the textbook's errata page and it said there that "Repertoire example is bad... needs to be replaced"....

Comment: @LinkL. No problem ! I suspected one more typo in a textbook. Cheers :-)